# Pandas Datetime Interval Resample to Seconds

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({"start": ["2017-01-01 13:09:01", "2017-01-01 13:09:07", "2017-01-01 13:09:12"],
         "end":    ["2017-01-01 13:09:05", "2017-01-01 13:09:09", "2017-01-01 13:09:14"],
         "status": ["OK", "ERROR", "OK"]})
```

HAVE:

```
| start               | end                 | status |
|---------------------|---------------------|--------|
| 2017-01-01 13:09:01 | 2017-01-01 13:09:05 | OK     |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:07 | 2017-01-01 13:09:09 | ERROR  | 
| 2017-01-01 13:09:12 | 2017-01-01 13:09:14 | OK     |
```

I want to convert it to another format, that is, "unfold" the intervals and make them into a DatetimeIndex, and resample the data. The result should look like this:

WANT:

```
|                     | status    |
|---------------------|-----------|
| 2017-01-01 13:09:01 | OK        |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:02 | OK        |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:03 | OK        |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:04 | OK        |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:05 | OK        |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:06 | NAN       |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:07 | ERROR     |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:08 | ERROR     |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:09 | ERROR     |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:10 | NAN       |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:11 | NAN       |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:12 | OK        |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:13 | OK        |
| 2017-01-01 13:09:14 | OK        |
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `IntervalIndex`:

```
# create an IntervalIndex from start/end
iv_idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['start'], df['end'], closed='both')

# generate the desired index of individual times
new_idx = pd.date_range(df['start'].min(), df['end'].max(), freq='s')

# set the index of 'status' as the IntervalIndex, then reindex to the new index
result = df['status'].set_axis(iv_idx, inplace=False).reindex(new_idx)
```

The resulting output for `result`:

```
2017-01-01 13:09:01       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:02       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:03       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:04       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:05       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:06      NaN
2017-01-01 13:09:07    ERROR
2017-01-01 13:09:08    ERROR
2017-01-01 13:09:09    ERROR
2017-01-01 13:09:10      NaN
2017-01-01 13:09:11      NaN
2017-01-01 13:09:12       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:13       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:14       OK
Freq: S, Name: status, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you that solution is way faster!

Comment: @root  I did try to recreate the same problem but the above solution throws me an error saying "'**<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int**'". I am not sure whether it is a datatype error or due to some other reason.

Comment: @karthikprasanna: String operations aren't supported for intervals in pandas (e.g. you can't have an interval from 'a' to 'm').  If don't have string data, make sure that your intervals and what you're reindexing against are of the correct dtype.  The error is indicating that at least one portion of your data is string.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this, using `apply` and rebuild series with `date_range`, then `resample` to fill missing time populated with NaN from `asfreq`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(x['start'], 
                                                 x['end'],
                                                 freq='S'), 
                             data=x['status']), axis=1)\
  .T\
  .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)\
  .resample('S').asfreq()
```

Output:

```
2017-01-01 13:09:01       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:02       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:03       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:04       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:05       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:06      NaN
2017-01-01 13:09:07    ERROR
2017-01-01 13:09:08    ERROR
2017-01-01 13:09:09    ERROR
2017-01-01 13:09:10      NaN
2017-01-01 13:09:11      NaN
2017-01-01 13:09:12       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:13       OK
2017-01-01 13:09:14       OK
Freq: S, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!